# Access an object referenced in other script but in the same game object

Tags: unity-game-engine

As the title says, I'm interested to access to an object that is referenced in other script but in the same Game Object (GameController). For now I referenced the same object in the script I want to use it (I referenced the same object two times,  once in each script) and it works just fine, but because both scripts are in the same game object, my question is if there are any way to access to this object more efficiently? I cannot use the static method because I need the reference from the inspector. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you are in script2, just type :
`GetComponent<script1>().ObjectToBeAccessed;` as long as variable "ObjectToBeAccessed" is declared publicly in script1;

Comment: It works! Just I needed to put that code contain in other variable in script2 and that's it. Thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

`gameObject.GetComponent<OtherScript>().otherObject` should do the trick if the particular object you were trying to get is public